# How do I move this drop down menu arrow - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I move this drop down menu arrow so it's not too close to the edge of the drop down menu?

[image]

```
    .footer_dropdown select {
        color:white;
        font-size:18px;
          -webkit-appearance:auto!important;
  /*webkit browsers */
  -moz-appearance: auto!important;
  /*Firefox */
  appearance: auto !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really style the default styling of browsers.

Simply remove the default styling from the select box by using `appearance: none;`

Then, add a `background-image` to the `select` tag and give it the proper styling you want. Take a look at my example. You can play a little with the settings.

Giving the position of the `background-image` with `calc`, where we place it 100% from the left, and subtract 20px from that; giving it basically the `right: 20px;` property. Placing it horizontally in the middle is what the 50% does after that.

Then we give it the `background-size` width and height both 15px; And we don't want it to repeat, so `no-repeat`.

```css
select{
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  
  background: #f9f9fa url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/32/32195.png') calc(100% - 20px) 50% / 15px 15px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
</select>
```